# Encode LoRaWAN packet

Tags: c#, lorawan

I have a system based on the LoRaWAN network. It gets the information from the Base64 encoded gateway. I need to decode it from NwkSKey and AppSKey into a valid HEX package. It is not about the simple functions of Base64ToHex but about decoding based on the keys. There is an online page for that, which tells me that my data is correct and that it can be decoded properly thanks to these keys. However, I need it on my agenda. I found some script in git:
https://github.com/sntcz/LoRa.Message
which decodes well, but without taking into account the keys. In the FRMPayload file, it seems to me that decoding is also taking place for the keys, but the Decrypt function is not called when the program starts.

I need something that will take my data, NwkSKey and AppSKey, and give me back what's in the picture, the second version of FRMPayload to be exact.

[image]

Ideally it should be in C# or Python.

Answer (score 0):

It's not written in C# or Python but it parses and composes LoRaWAN Messages. It's from the TTN Network, see https://github.com/brocaar/lorawan and it is written in Golang.